# GA4 BigQuery Export doesn't export all the data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've enabled BigQuery Export in Google Analytics 4, but on inspection I noticed that roughly half of the events were missing in the raw data (in my case those were sign_up events that also had user_id as a parameter).

When inspecting the event stats in the standard GA4 report I noticed that "Data Thresholding" was applied when inspecting stats pertaining to the said event. My understanding is that when thresholding is applied, GA4 omits certain events from exporting, although I can't be sure of that.

Is there a way to make sure all the data gets exported to BigQuery?

Comment: How did you inspect your raw data? In my case, I press "EXPORT" -> "Explore with Sheets". Then I can see only the first 500 rows of my Google Analytics 4 data. This is because Google Sheet only displays the first 500 rows in a sheet as a preview.